# Navigationbar button hide when open UIDocumentInteractionController

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uidocumentinteraction

I use UIDocumentInteractionController for Open the Document and share in crome,take print, send email etc. but my problem is this when i open the UIDocumentInteractionController it hides the button of Navigationbar button (Done button and share button).

Comment: Did you found any reason why the buttons would hided?

Comment: did u get solution to it or any reason why is it happening?